# How can I trace only once?

Tags: r, debugging

Just like we have `debugonce` that we can use instead of the `debug` / `undebug` couple, it would be nice to have a `traceonce` function to use instead of `trace` / `untrace`.

How can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with:

```r
traceonce <- function(what, tracer, exit, at, print, signature,
                       where = topenv(parent.frame()), edit = FALSE){
  mc <- match.call()
  mc[[1]] <- quote(trace)
  mc[["exit"]] <-
    if (missing(exit)) substitute(quote(eval.parent(quote(untrace(what)))))
    else c(as.expression(exit), substitute(eval.parent(quote(untrace(what)))))
  eval.parent(mc)
}
```

I edit the formals of the call so I don't have to deal with a bunch of checks on `missing`, then I edit the `exit` element of the call (2 cases, exists or not) to add a call to untrace on the given function.

---

With `exit` argument :

```
traceonce(head, exit = quote({print("hello")}))
#> Tracing function "head" in package "utils"
#> [1] "head"
head(cars,1)
#> Tracing head(cars, 1) on exit 
#> [1] "hello"
#> Untracing function "head" in package "utils"
#>   speed dist
#> 1     4    2
head(cars,1)
#>   speed dist
#> 1     4    2
```

Without `exit` argument:

```
traceonce(head, quote({print("hello")}))
#> Tracing function "head" in package "utils"
#> [1] "head"
head(cars,1)
#> Tracing head(cars, 1) on entry 
#> [1] "hello"
#> Tracing head(cars, 1) on exit
#> Untracing function "head" in package "utils"
#>   speed dist
#> 1     4    2
head(cars,1)
#>   speed dist
#> 1     4    2
```